# JSON schema: Property value must be equal to parent key

Tags: json, jsonschema, ajv, python-jsonschema

According to [JSON-Schema 7.0 String section](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html#json-pointer), I can use a `"relative-json-pointer"` to make sure that a property value is an exact match of a parent key.

In the examples section (5.1) of [Relative JSON Pointers](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-relative-json-pointer-02), it shows that "going up one level" and get the key value, is `"0#"`.

Given the following JSON document:

```json
{
    "valid": {
        "name": "valid"
    },
    "invalid": {
        "name": "invalid, because this value is not the same value as the parent key"
    }
}
```

The following json-schema should catch the `"invalid"` object:

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": ["name"],
        "properties": {
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "json-pointer": "0#"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am sure the json-schema is sound, since it will catch the two objects, `"invalid2"` and `"invalid3"`, in the following JSON document:

```json
{
    "valid": {
        "name": "valid"
    },
    "invalid": {
        "name": "invalid, because this value is not the same value as the parent key"
    },
    "invalid2": {   },
    "invalid3": { "name": 2 }
}
```

I have used [ajv-cli 3.3.0](https://github.com/jessedc/ajv-cli#readme) and [python jsonschema 3.2.0](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to test with. But neither validation implementations will catch the `"invalid"` object. Both implementations claim to fully support JSON Schema draft 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can use a "relative-json-pointer" to make sure that a property value
> is an exact match of a parent key.

I'm not sure how you're reading that section, but that's not what it says at all.

That section you reference, on the documentation site, is listing a set of built-in possible values for the `format` keyword.

It does nothing WITH the value you want to validate, for example, a `relative-json-pointer`.

What is it you WANT to do?

Comment: You are right that it is related to `format`. I will try that. But it does say "Note that this should be used only when the entire string contains only JSON Pointer content" for `"json-pointer"`. I assume the same is true for `"relative-json-pointer"` in the same section.

Comment: Yes. It notes that the WHOLE string must be a JSON pointer, such as `/foo/bar` as opposed to a uri-reference such as `#/foo/bar/`.

Comment: The json-pointer that you're validating with `format: json-pointer` is in the instance. The pointer isn't in the schema. There is no `json-pointer` keyword.

Comment: Well, since it's a built-in I suppose that I can not use Relative JSON Pointers in the schema but only if they were in the JSON document. To answer your question: I want to catch the `"invalid"` object as an error, since its `"name"` property does not equal its object key.

Comment: I see. No, you can't do that in JSON Schema. Schemas cannot reference locations in the instance.

Comment: I have looked at "`$ref"` and `"$id"` but fail to see how I can set the required value of the `name` property with those...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224205/discussion-between-dotnetcarpenter-and-relequestual).